# Can TeamCity 6.0.3 Emails Be Set to Show a List of Changes?

Tags: teamcity

In TeamCity 6.0.3, I would like emails to show a list of individual file changes with the user that changed them, like Cruise Control does.  Out of the box, it only shows a summary such as "User A (2 files)".  Is there a way to change the email format to display the individual changes?

Answer (score 0):

Try using var.buildChanges in your notification template. Please see more documentation [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Customizing+Notifications).

Comment: I've looked at the template and by default it uses {var.buildChanges}, which appears to only provide a summary such as "Changes included (1 change). Change 12345 by User A (8 files): <no comment>".  I would like to see a full listing of the files that were changed instead of the summary.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever got it to work. I also was facing this issue and stumbled upon the following on Stackoverflow -

[Show Changes with Files in TeamCity 5.1 Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2678837/2279816)

The second answer by @bret worked for me. The answer is for Teamcity 6. I'm using Teamcity 8.0